# How to create a hotpluggable dummy monitor in X11?

Tags: linux, display, multiple-monitors, xorg

I want to make a hotpluggable dummy monitor in X11.
Basically what I want is, a dummy monitor should be present only if no screens are connected to the device. If at least one screen is connected, the display shouldn't exist. This should happen even when the system is already booted, for example:

No display connected on boot, after 2 hours, a display is connected, after 3 more hours, the display is disconnected:
For the first 2 hours, there should be a dummy display. after the display is connected, the dummy display should be gone. after 3 more hours, as there are no displays connected to the system now, the dummy display should be present again.

I'm running Fedora, but preferably, I want a solution to work on most distros.

All the solutions I found either have the dummy display always plugged in, or they only get connected when the system doesn't detect a display on boot, and not after that.

I'm adding what I found on my searches:

1. https://askubuntu.com/questions/453109/add-fake-display-when-no-monitor-is-plugged-in
2. https://techoverflow.net/2019/02/23/how-to-run-x-server-using-xserver-xorg-video-dummy-driver-on-ubuntu/
3. https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=246284

Comment: This question is very interesting, and something I've been looking for too for months. I haven't found any ad-hoc way within Xorg configuration. Have you found a way to do this ? The only way I could think of is simple bash scripts, but I'm not even sure Xorg is able to replace its (only) monitor at runtime.

Comment: @adamency i gave up and ended up buying a physical dummy HDMI adapter. it's not the most ideal solution, so if someone can come up with a solution for this someday, i'm sure it would be useful to many

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I did it:

Create a `xorg.conf` file, I've placed it under `/root/`:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier "Configured Video Device"
    Driver "dummy"
    VideoRam 256000
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "Configured Monitor"
    HorizSync 28.0-80.0
    VertRefresh 48.0-75.0
    Modeline "1920x1080_60.00" 172.80 1920 2040 2248 2576 1080 1081 1084 1118 -HSync +Vsync
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Default Screen"
    Monitor "Configured Monitor"
    Device "Configured Video Device"
    DefaultDepth 24
    SubSection "Display"
        Depth 24
        Modes "1920x1080_60.00"
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

The script checks every 5 seconds whether a monitor was connected (or disconnected) and copies (or removes) the configuration file to/from xorg's conf.d folder when the state changes:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Change according to your needs
XORG_CONF_SOURCE="/root/xorg.conf"
XORG_CONF_DEST="/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/xorg.conf"

CONN_STATUS=""

# Function to check and switch displays
switch_display() {
    if check_monitor_connected; then
        if [ "$CONN_STATUS" != "yes" ]; then
            # Disable the dummy display
            echo Monitor connected
            rm $XORG_CONF_DEST
            service display-manager restart
            CONN_STATUS="yes"
        fi
    else
        if [ "$CONN_STATUS" != "no" ]; then
            # Enable the dummy display
            echo Monitor disconnected
            cp $XORG_CONF_SOURCE $XORG_CONF_DEST
            service display-manager restart
            CONN_STATUS="no"
        fi
    fi
}

# Function to check if a monitor is connected
check_monitor_connected() {
    for card in /sys/class/drm/card*; do
        if [ -e "$card/status" ]; then
            status=$(cat "$card/status")
            if [ "$status" = "connected" ]; then
                return 0  # Monitor connected
            fi
        fi
    done
    return 1  # No monitor connected
}

# Continuous loop to monitor for changes
while true; do
    switch_display
    # Check every 5 seconds for changes
    sleep 5
done
```